# how to send application/x-www-form-urlencoded in Spring 6 RestClient

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I use spring-web 6.1.1. Below is working for RestTemplate

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String url = "https://dev-test.com/token";

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

MultiValueMap<String, String> map= new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
map.add("username", "aaa");
map.add("password", "bbc");
map.add("grant_type", "password");

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity( url, request, String.class );
```

When using new RestClient, I got the error:

```
RestClient test = RestClient.builder()
                .baseUrl("https://dev-test.com/")
                .build();

        ResponseEntity responseLicenseCheck = test.post()
                .uri("/token")
                .body(request)
                .retrieve()
                .toEntity(String.class);
```

--

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: "{"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}"
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:103)
```

Comment: provide minimum executable demo , not sure your dependency

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the necessary header for your request

```
RestClient test = RestClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("https://dev-test.com/")
            .build();

    ResponseEntity responseLicenseCheck = test.post()
            .uri("/token")
            .body(request)
            ..contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED) // this one
            .retrieve()
            .toEntity(String.class);
```